# Firefox CORS issue with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, cors

I'm trying to use the API from https://www.themoviedb.org/. (The key is free and can be changed easily, so I'll include it because without it, you can’t even test their functions).

Now my JavaScript is working fine in FF when it's hosted local, but not on GitHub pages.

Here is a function that doesn’t work. Error is:

> NetworkError: A network error occurred.

…and it appears to happen after `bhttp.send();`.

```js
function getMovieDetails() {
  var reqURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/latest?api_key=afe4e10abbb804e2b4a4f8a3ef067ad5&language=en-US";
  var bhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  bhttp.open("GET", reqURL, false);
  bhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "json");
  bhttp.send();
  var response = JSON.parse(bhttp.responseText);
  var str = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
  return response;
}
console.log(getMovieDetails());
```

It works fine in Chrome. Googling appears to indicate it’s a CORS problem, but as far as I know GitHub pages  supports CORS, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark here, but using sync requests are bad, and discouraged, so I wonder if FF is blocking it.

Comment: Y thats showing up in the console, but since it works locally i thought it works hosted aswell. Whats the aproach to make it better?

Comment: Found this -> `Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.`  So I assume if you change your code to asynchronous you should be good to go.  link -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: by the way saying `GitHub pages supports CORS` is irrelevant - the question in your code is, does `api.themoviedb.org` send CORS headers? answer: it does

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright looks like skirtle was correct, the issue was the firefox addon Privacy-Badger blocking the API. I feel pretty stupid now but at least my code is now pretty clean.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a firefox user, so you will need to test this.  But if the theory of async blocking is true this should work.

I've modified it to use a simple callback, personally I wouldn't use callbacks but would make into promises, but that's another question :)

```js
function getMovieDetails(callback) {
  var reqURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/latest?api_key=afe4e10abbb804e2b4a4f8a3ef067ad5&language=en-US";
  var bhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  bhttp.open("GET", reqURL, true);
  bhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "json");
  bhttp.onload = function() {
        if (bhttp.readyState === 4) {
            if (bhttp.status === 200) {
                callback(JSON.parse(bhttp.responseText));
            } else {
                console.error(bhttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
  bhttp.send();
}

getMovieDetails(function (movie) {
  console.log(movie);
});
```

Comment: Seems like it really was a synchron/asynchron issue, I'm still new to doing webdev things so I don't really know much best practices yet

Comment: Glad that this is fixed but I'm not convinced it was a sync/async issue. I tried using Firefox and GitHub pages with the original sync code and everything worked fine. One thing I tried that did cause the original error was using an invalid `api_key`, which makes me wonder whether it was just a JS caching issue?

Comment: It could well be something else, but the `deprecated` tag, is a good reason to stay away anyway.